# why akka.net IActorRef.Tell()，the message parameter's field doesn't need to be volatile?

Tags: volatile, akka.net

why learning akka.net, i release when call IActorRef.Tell, the parameter's field doesn't need to be volatile

```
public class Model{
        public volatile string Name;
    }
```

In the following example,  Name property doesn't need to be volatile.

```
using System;
using Akka.Actor;

namespace WinTail
{
    class Program
    {
        public static ActorSystem MyActorSystem;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // make an actor system 
            MyActorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("MyActorSystem");

            // make our first actors!
            IActorRef consoleWriterActor = MyActorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ConsoleWriterActor()),
                "consoleWriterActor");

            Model model = new Model();
            model.Name = "jack";
            model.Name = "tom";
            // tell console reader to begin
            consoleReaderActor.Tell(model);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }


    public class Model{
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[The `volatile` keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Because message immutability is one of the [key principles](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html#messages-and-immutability) when designing an actor-based system, volatile modifiers are not needed as messages should be immutable. To be safe, you would need to change your `Model` to be immutable.